# Problemas al realizar un query set de aquellas ligas que tengan eventos filtrados por una fecha timestamps

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Se tienen dos modelos donde se necesita realizar un filtro de aquellas ligas que tenga juegos en una fecha dada, dicha fecha es un timestamp ejemplo=: `1698292800` todo esto funciona bien el problema es que al obtener los resultados de dicho filtros este trae eventos de otras fechas incluyendo aquella que se filtro

## Modelos

> Modelo FootballLeague este contiene todas las ligas de futbol

```
class FootballLeague(UUIDModel, TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255, db_index=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(
        _("Country"), max_length=255, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True
    )
    country_id = models.IntegerField(_("Country ID"), null=True, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Football League")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Football Leagues")
        ordering = ["name"]
```

> Modelo EventsFootball este contiene todos los juegos en relación a una liga

```
class EventsFootball(UUIDModel):
    event_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_time = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    home_score_current = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    home_score_part_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    home_score_part_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   
    home_images = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    away_score_current = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    away_score_part_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    away_score_part_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    info_notice = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    away_images = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        FootballLeague, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.league.name} - {self.round}"
```

> La relacion o query realizado hasta el momento  donde se traen los juegos de la fecha filtrada aqui todo marcha bien al realizar un print de eventos_filtrados trae aquellos juegos que esta en esa fecha

```
eventos_filtrados = EventsFootball.objects.filter(
            start_time__gte=timestamp_inicio, start_time__lte=timestamp_fin
        ).values_list("event_id", flat=True)
```

> Aqui el problema al obtener el resultado trae las ligas pero con eventos que no estan en el primer primer filtro

```
queryset = FootballLeague.objects.filter(
            events__event_id__in=eventos_filtrados,
        )
```

> Ejemplo del resultado donde solo en events deberia trae dicho evento con fecha 2023-10-27

```
{
    "links": {
        "next": null,
        "previous": null
    },
    "count": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "short_name": "UEFA Nations League Femenina",
            "name": "Europa: UEFA Nations League Femenina - Liga A",
            "tournament_stage_id": "rgU5w0eQ",
            "tournament_id": null,
            "tournament_image": "https://www.flashscore.com/res/image/data/Q7GMJzmd-SWnXZ8VO.png",
            "tournament_season_id": "jZ4CaGVm",
            "group_id": null,
            "template_id": "6_GWpMLXB0",
            "events": [
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-28 12:30:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "YuP7vwa9",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-30 13:00:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "0hAjFMVc",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-17 14:30:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "2eg8JyNq",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-12 14:45:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "0W2fCabJ",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-21 14:45:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "A3e82qnh",
                },
                {
                    "start_time": "2023-10-27 11:45:00",
                    "favorite": false,
                    "event_id": "pvBbUhy2",
                }
            ],
            "country": {
                "flag": "/media/livescores/upload/country_flag_6.png",
                "code": "Europa"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```